# How to quit grub rescue after rm -rf*？

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I tried removing Ubuntu by rm -rf*, but it seems to fail. After removing it, I can't get into the bios after booting, I can only get into grub rescue, and I'm told /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found. I remade the system usb and tried to boot the partition to the grub of the system disk, but was told i386-pc/normal.mod does not exist. The data on my hard drive doesn't matter, I just want to reinstall an Ubuntu system right now. How to solve this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to reinstall an Ubuntu system right now. How to solve this problem

Use a cold boot to start the system. And you can enter your BIOS. The from there pick the USB as the bootable option.  Then boot from the live session and the installer will format your system for you.

> How to quit grub rescue after rm -rf*？

control-alt-delete to reboot or turn the machine off and on again.

---

> After removing it, I can't get into the bios after booting,

Those two have no correlation

> I can only get into grub rescue, and I'm told /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found.

That means you pressed the wrong key or too early or too late to enter your BIOS. The "not found" is likely related to your "rm" but not important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Maybe I can't express it clearly. My problem is that when I restart, it will enter the grub rescue directly , so I can't enter by pressing the button to enter the bios.
 Under normal circumstances, the key button of the bios is f12, but no matter how I press it,  the system will still enter the grub rescue system. Therefore, I have no way to boot and reinstall the system with the uefi of the usb.
I would like to know, how to exit grub rescue and enter the bios installation system, or use my system disk to fix the system directly.

Comment: No there is a bit of time between a cold boot and grub where you can press a key to enter BIOS. Maybe it is not f12 for you. It depends on the model.

Comment: Many UEFI systems have a fast boot setting where system immediately boots. No system scan for changes is made, it assumes entire system has no changes. Then a "cold" boot or full power down will use a full boot with scan of system, giving just enough time to press f2 to get into UEFI/BIOS or f12 for boot menu, if those are the correct keys for your system.